# How can I optimize a matlab based audio visualizer that requires multiple bandpass filters?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

**The Problem**

I have been given an assignment to design an audio visualizer using FFT in matlab. I have gotten through most of what I want to do with the audio visualizer, bit I'm running into problems with running the program smoothly because it is throttled by my processor. I want to do more with my visualizer but I don't want to implement anymore features before I can get the basics to run well.

**Background**

The program is really two parts. The first part is the audio player and runs a matlab script called `CLICK_ME.m`. The second is `currentfft()`. It takes in the information from the song and before I have borked it, it plotted the (frequency, power). However this is the most basic visualizer and my professor wants us to create a unique audio visualizer.

My idea was to graph one of those stat pentagons where the radius to each of the five points is the power filtered between five bands of frequencies.

Naturally, I implemented matlab's `bandpass()` function and this does what it is designed to do. However it takes a lot more processing power than I could have anticipated and subsequently it is being bottlenecked and looks really choppy.

I have tried decreasing the number of points it has to perform calculations on by using a for loop to take every other or every third value. I have done this up to a reduction by quotient of ten to no noticeable success. If I remove more than every tenth point, I get errors from matlab that it can't do a `bandpass()` on less than six samples.

My professor suggested taking the `gaussmf()` or the `rectangularPulse()` to simulate something close to a bandpass filter but I'm not certain how to implement them or if they will be any faster.

```
function currentfft ( player, Y, FS )

sampleNumber = get( player, 'CurrentSample' );
timerVal = get( player, 'TimerPeriod' );

%Get channel one values for our window around the current sample number
s1 = Y(floor(sampleNumber-((timerVal*FS)/2)):floor(sampleNumber+((timerVal*FS)/2)),1);

n = length(s1);
p = fft(s1); % take the fourier transform

nUniquePts = ceil((n+1)/2);
p = p(1:nUniquePts);    % select just the first half since the second half
                        % is a mirror image of the first

p = abs(p);             % take the absolute value, or the magnitude

p = p/n;                % scale by the number of points so that
                        % the magnitude does not depend on the length
                        % of the signal or on its sampling frequency

p = p.^2;               % square it to get the power

% multiply by two
if rem(n, 2) % odd nfft excludes Nyquist point
    p(2:end) = p(2:end)*2;
else
    p(2:end -1) = p(2:end -1)*2;
end


% reduce the number of points actually being filtered
q = 1;
s = 1;
d = int16( length(p) );

pNew = zeros( [ d/10, 1 ] );

while q < d
    pNew(s) = p(q);
    q = q + 10;
    s = s + 1;
end

% try gaussian or rect functions instead of bandpass?

% radius of each section of the pentagon
p0 = abs( bandpass(pNew, [ 1 60 ], FS) );
p1 = abs( bandpass(pNew, [ 60 250 ], FS) );
p2 = abs( bandpass(pNew, [ 250 2e3 ], FS) );
p3 = abs( bandpass(pNew, [ 2e3 8e3 ], FS) );
p4 = abs( bandpass(pNew, [ 8e3 20e3 ], FS) );

% length( p0 )
% length( p1 )
% length( p2 )
% length( p3 )
% length( p4 )

pArr = [ p0, p1, p2, p3, p4 ];

%freqArray = (0:nUniquePts-1) * (FS / n); % create the frequency array

thetaArr = [ pi/2, 4.5*pi/5, 6.5*pi/5, 8.5*pi/5, 10.5*pi/5 ];


% calculating x and y from the radii 
x = cos(thetaArr) ./ pArr; 
y = sin(thetaArr) ./ pArr;

plot(x, y)
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Power (watts)')
title('Frequency vs. Power')
grid on;
axis([-20e9 20e9 -20e9 20e9]);
```

I would love for this code to run smoothly without taking my processor through the wringer. It, however, doesn't run smoothly and maxes out two threads on my computer.

Comment: I don't understand why the bandpass filters are needed at all. If you already have the frequency spectrum you could simply just consider the individual bands of your spectrum you are interested in. In a way that would be like applying ideal bandpass filter to your signal anyway. Simply take the first 60 bins of your spectrum for the first band, the next 60 bins for the second band and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify. This approach would come down to multiplying your frequency response (fft output) with a shifted rectangular window to obtain an individual band

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't really gone over shifted rectangular windows yet. I know that there exists a function called rectwin() takes in a single argument for the length of the window, but I'm not sure how one could shift it? I'v been scouring the audio processing and signal processing documentation to find anything useful, to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`bandpass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html) function filters the provided input samples directly, resulting in a 'smoothed' version in the same domain. In your case that input is already the frequency-domain representation, so you'd be getting a smoothed frequency-domain representation, which isn't what you are trying to achieve (which would instead be the power of a smoothed time-domain representation).

Instead, since you already have the frequency-domain representation, you could simply select the correct frequency bins (which is essentially what applying a rectangular window in the frequency-domain would do).

```
p0 = sum(pNew((floor(1*n/FS)+1):(floor(60*n/FS)+1)));
p1 = sum(pNew((floor(60*n/FS)+1):(floor(250*n/FS)+1)));
p2 = sum(pNew((floor(250*n/FS)+1):(floor(2e3*n/FS)+1)));
p3 = sum(pNew((floor(2e3*n/FS)+1):(floor(8e3*n/FS)+1)));
p4 = sum(pNew((floor(8e3*n/FS)+1):(floor(20e3*n/FS)+1)));
```

If you are still going to downsampling your FFT, you may instead want to equivalently (but more efficiently) sum smaller FFTs:

```
% pad to a size that is a multiple of the block size
D = 10;
L = ceil(n/D);
M = L*D;
s2 = zeros(1,M);
s2(1:length(s1)) = s1;
% compute the downsampled FFT by summing smaller FFTs
p = zeros(1,L);
for i = 0:(D-1)
    p = p + fft(s2((1+i*L):(1+L+i*L)));
end
```